# Which statistical tests to re: hypothesis testing with 2 IV's and 2 DV's in pre-test-post-test design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, multiple-regression, pearson-r

I'm doing data analysis for my first hypothesis testing in a research proposal for an introductory psychology research methods course and would like some advice on which statistical tests to use.

I'm not sure whether to use two-factor ANOVA, multiple regression, Pearson's R, a combination of both, or something else... Here's an overview of the study:

Research question: does mindfulness affect stress and blood pressure levels?

Design is 3 independent groups: Meditation session, Breathing session, Control session

2 dependent variables are measured: blood pressure measurement (systolic and diastolic pressure measured; pre-test-post-test) and STAI (self-reporting questionnaire) score (post test only).

Please let me know if you need more information. I thought this was straightforward at first but I am almost at my wit's end!